# How to manage the gap between menu's icon and text as they are getting overlapped after getting clicked, for BottomNavigationView?

Tags: java, android-xml, menuitem, android-menu, bottomnavigationview

I have increased the size of "**menu icon**", and that's why its getting overlapped with "**menu text**".

So for that I have managed the gap between them using the following method ***"menuAlignment()"***, but somehow after clicking on "**menu item**", the gap between "**menu icon**" and "**menu text**" is getting back to its previous state i.e. overlapped, please help me on this.

My code is as follows:

```
    public void menuAlignment()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < menuView.getChildCount(); i++) {
            final View iconView = menuView.getChildAt(i).findViewById(android.support.design.R.id.icon);

            final FrameLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (FrameLayout.LayoutParams) iconView.getLayoutParams();
            final DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
            // set your height here
            layoutParams.height = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 27, displayMetrics);
            // set your width here
            layoutParams.width = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 28, displayMetrics);

            layoutParams.gravity=Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL;
            layoutParams.setMargins(0,0,0,200);

            iconView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

            //  iconView.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 10);
        }
}
```

Code for "**navigationClickListener**":-

```
private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener
            = new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.navigation_jokes_word:
                    loadFragment(new JokesFragment());
                    menuAlignment();
                    return true;
                case R.id.navigation_jokes_images:
                    loadFragment(new ImageJokesFragment());
                    menuAlignment();
                    return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    };
```

navigation.xml [menu.xml]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/navigation_word"
        android:icon="@drawable/digital"
        android:title="@string/title_jokes_word"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/navigation_images"
        android:icon="@drawable/images"
        android:title="@string/title_jokes_images" />


</menu>
```

MyActivity's screenshot:

[BottomNavigationView's menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HmahB.png)

Comment: for an easy alternative you can use an image which have some extra padding around it

Comment: How can I do that, as you can see in "navigation.xml", I am setting an menu icon using ' android:icon="@drawable/digital" '

Comment: Use a different image

Comment: I can do that, but that won't solve the problem, I might have to set the desire image with no padding, mostly I am not sure about what I am saying....

Comment: In that case you have to create the bottom view manually using Layouts instead of using menu xml

Comment: You said you want space between them and then you are saying you don't want any padding. You really are confused

Comment: That's a long way to go brother, as I have to submit this thing within very short period of time, but thanks I might dig in for that...

Comment: That's why I told you the easy way before

Comment: get a different png image.If you had a designer ask them to give them

Comment: There is no designer, if you have solution for this, then please let me know...

Answer (score 1):

Menu item view

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_home"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_home_blue_48dp"
    android:title="Home" />
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_menu"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_apps_black_24dp"
    android:title="Menu"
     />
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_msg"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_chat_black_24dp"
    android:title="Message Inbox"
   />
</menu>
```

click listener

```
bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item)
        {
            Fragment selectedFragment = null;
            switch (item.getItemId())
            {
                case R.id.action_home:
                    /*hide extra toolbars*/
                    hideViews();
                    /*hide back button*/
                    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
                    selectedFragment = new TimelineFragment();
                    break;
                case R.id.action_menu:
                    hideViews();
                    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
                    selectedFragment = new HomeFragment();
                    break;
                case R.id.action_msg:
                    hideViews();
                    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
                    selectedFragment = new ChatFragment();
                    break;
            }
```